# How to save data from drop down option value to laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel-4, mysqli, eloquent, laravel-5

// form

```
<form method="post">
<div>
<label>Result:</label>
<div class="select">
<select name="result" id="result" class="result">
<option value="1">First Division</option>
<option value="2">Second Division</option>
<option value="3">Third Division</option>
<option value="4">Grade</option>
</select>
</div>
Marks/CGPA.
</div>
<div class="marks">
<label>Marks(%):</label>
<input name="marks" class="form-control marksText" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="cgpa">
<div class="col-md-5">
<label>CGPA:</label>
<input name="cgpa" id="cgpa" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-5">
<label>Scale:</label>
<input name="scale" id="scale" class="scale" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="save">
<button type="button">Close</button>
 <input type="submit" name="save_education" value="Save changes" />
 </div>
</form>
```

// controller

```
if(isset($_POST['save_education])){
    $qualification = Qualification::create(array
        (   
         'level_of_education' => $input['level_education'],
         'exam_title' =>  $input['exam_title'],
         'major' = $input['major'],

          if(isset($_POST([$input['result]))){
               $r = $input['result'];
               if($r == 1){
                  $result => 'First';
                  $marks = $input['marks'];
                  }
              elseif ($r == 2){
                  $result => 'Second';
                  $marks = $input['marks'];
                  }
               elseif ($r == 3){
                  $result => 'Third';
                  $marks = $input['marks'];
              }
              else {
                  if($r == 4)
                     $result = $input['cgpa'];
                     $marks = $input['scale'];
                   }
          }
         .....
        )
    );

    $qualification->save();
}
```

I am using laravel4.2, when i attempt to save result it shows error(unexpected if in isset result line), what is wrong with me. how to save data into database after checking the option value. As a newbie of laravel pls help me..It ruins my all day....pls..help...

Comment: It looks like your specific error is coming from an extra ")"  on this line: if(isset($_POST([$input['result])))

Comment: but what should i do? after removing it also shows error:: 'syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ')''... @retrograde ...can u help me...i am just unable to save with my condition....pls help..

Answer (score 1):

If this is your live code, you're lacking some quotes in the first and eight line:

```
if(isset($_POST['save_education])){ //old
if(isset($_POST['save_education'])){ //new

if(isset($_POST([$input['result]))){ //old
if(isset($_POST([$input['result']))){ //new
```

Also, it would be a good idea to use laravel specific functions and not plain PHP. Replace your `$_POST['blub']` commands with `\Input::get('blub')`. You can check if a var is available by using `\Input::has('blub')`.

For further security, you should also do some validation. An example would be:

```
$validator = \Validator::make(
    \Input::all(),
    [
         'result' => 'required|between:1,4',
         'marks' => 'do-further-stuff',
         [...]
    ]
);
if($validator->fails()) {
    // error handling, go back or something
} else {
    // success, do what you want
}
```

For validation rules have a look into [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#available-validation-rules).

Answer (score 0):

IMO it seems like the ::create array is confusing the basics.   Also, I'm not clear what you are doing with $result and $marks - I am assuming they are columns on your Qualification table.

I recommend doing something like this:

```
$r = $input::get('result');

 if($r){
    $q = new Qualification;
    $q->level_of_education = Input::get('level_education');
     // do the same thing with the rest of your fields

    if($r == 1) {
       $q->result = 'First';
       $q->marks = Input::get('marks');
      }
    // rest of your elseif statements would follow 

   $q->save();
}
```

This site has a great CRUD tutorial (this is addressed about 1/2 way through): https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-laravel-crud-with-resource-controllers

Good luck